# C# Generic Class Inheritance confusion

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

```
abstract class BaseClassA{}

class DerivedClassA : BaseClassA{}

abstract class BaseClassB<T> where T : BaseClassA
{    
  public T foo;
}

class DerivedClassB : BaseClassB<DerivedClassA>
{
  public DerivedClassB(DerivedClassA _foo)
  {
    foo = _foo;
  }
}

class Test
{
  DerivedClassB foobar = new DerivedClassB();
  void main()
  {
    //Error: casting not possible
    BaseClassA<BaseClassB> bar = new DerivedClassA<DerivedClassB>(foobar);
  }
}
```

Hey everyone.
I have a little problem. The code above gives me a "cannot cast" Exception.
I want to be able to access foo of DerivedClassB without casting it from BaseClassA to DerivedClassA.

Can't I have a generic type derive from the Base Class and still use it?

Comment: `DerivedClassA` is not generic in your example. Class `BaseClass<T>` is completely missing.

Comment: @dymanoid: I think they meant `BaseClass<T>` to be `BaseClassB<T>`  perhaps?

Comment: Your code is full of typos and so does not clearly demonstrate the problem. **Write your question carefully so as to not waste the time of the people who are trying to help you**.

Comment: I _guess_ your problem has to do with _variance_, but I can't tell, because the posted code does not make sense. `DerivedClassA` is not generic, so what should `new DerivedClassA<DerivedClassB>` mean?

Comment: René Vogt is correct; your problem almost certainly has to do with misunderstanding covariance. **This question is asked almost every day here so do some research**.  Probably what is happening is that you believe that a `Bowl<Apples>` should be usable as a `Container<Fruit>` because bowls are a kind of container and apples are a kind of fruit. **That is bad logic**.  You can put a banana into a container of fruit, but you cannot put a banana into a bowl of apples, and therefore the two types are not compatible. They admit different operations.

Comment: and `BaseClassA` also isn't generic, so your whole `main` method doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also, don't forget that `main` has to be `static` and capitalized in C#.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that if what you want were legal then this would also be legal:

```
abstract class Animal {}
class Goldfish : Animal {}
class Giraffe : Animal {}
abstract class Cage<T> where T : Animal {
   void Add(T newAnimal) { ... }
}
class Aquarium : Cage<Goldfish> { }
...
Cage<Animal> c = new Aquarium(); // This is not legal, but suppose it was
c.Add(new Giraffe()); // A giraffe is an animal
```

And now we have a giraffe in an aquarium, delighting no one.

This feature is called *covariance* and it only works on *generic interface and delegates*, when they are constructed with *reference types*, and they are *designed specifically to handle variance and checked for safety by the compiler*.

For example, you can use an `IEnumerable<Fish>` in a context where an `IEnumerable<Animal>` is expected because there is no way to add a giraffe to a sequence of animals.

> Can't I have a generic type derive from the Base Class and still use it?

Yes but you have to follow the rules. **Those rules are there to keep you safe**.  Learn how the type system works and work with it to help prevent your bugs, and you will never put a giraffe in an aquarium by mistake.